# nginx: redirecting to SSL based on the original request URL (not $server_name)

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx config that is similar to this:

```
server {
  server_name my-english-site.com my-french-site.com;

  listen 0.0.0.0:80;

  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
  server_name my-english-site.com my-french-site.com;
}
```

When someone goes to http://my-french-site.com, it redirects to https://my-english-site.com, because the rewrite directive uses the first server in the `$server_name` directive.

I tried replacing `$server_name` with `$host`, expecting it to use the value of the `Host` request header. But it still redirects to the English URL.

How can I get non-HTTPS requests redirected to the corresponding HTTPS URLs?

Thank you!

Comment: `$host` is the correct way to do it, however it may be empty if the client sends no HOST header.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I just tried this again, and it works. Not sure why it didn't work for me the first time. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably that you were doing your tests with permanent redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using the `$host` variable is the way to do it (thanks @gparent). I just tested it again and it works.